Can I setup Playwright on a private server?
I need to setup if its possible a server to run my test in a private mode, where the tests doesnt run on the servers of Playwright
I need to the part of the server be on the client side if its possible, thanks by the way
enter image description here

By default Playwright runs on a private server. Playwright doesn't host test servers as far as I know. I'm not sure I understand the question.
